# Why doesn't CreateWindowW accept an ATOM as the lpClassName?

Tags: c++, winapi

In the MSDN description of [CreateWindowW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww), the window class name (lpClassName) can either be a text string or an ATOM type.

I intend to use the predefined COMBOBOX several times, so the specific ATOM seems to be the better solution.

```
ATOM MyRegisterConnectClass(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    WNDCLASSEXW wcon;

    wcon.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcon.lpszClassName = TEXT("COMBOBOX");
    wcon.lpfnWndProc = ConnectProc;  
    // and all the other attributes

    RegisterClassExW(&wcon);
}

BOOL InitConnect(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hConnect = CreateWindowW(
        RegisterClassExW(&wcon), // lpClassName,
        TEXT("Connect"), // lpWindowName,
        CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_SIMPLE | WS_OVERLAPPED, // dwStyle,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // x,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // y,
        0, // nWidth,
        0, // nHeight,
        hWnd, // hWndParent,
        nullptr, // hMenu,
        hInstance, // hInstance,
        nullptr // lpParam
    );

 if (hConnect) {
       OutputDebugStringW(L"InitConnect() successfully created hConnect\n");
       ShowWindow(hConnect, nCmdShow);
       UpdateWindow(hConnect);
           return TRUE;
   } else {
       OutputDebugStringW(L"InitConnect() failed to create hConnect\n");
       return FALSE;
   }
}
```

The code above generates error [C2664](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2664)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160).

I get a compiler failure with `COMBOBOX, //lpClassName`

```
HWND hConnect = CreateWindowW(
   WC_COMBOBOX, //lpClassName
```

compiles fine, but hConnect isn't created.

I tried to capture the ATOM thusly but it didn't work.
`ATOM acon = MyRegisterConnectClass( ...`

Comment: What are type1 and type2 of C2664? Anyhow, the solution is probably a simple cast, but try searching here for "CreateWindow ATOM" and read a few of the discussions. BTW: Get rid of those `TEXT()` macros around string literals, unless you really need a `TCHAR` string. The second parameter to `CreateWindowW()`, just to name one, is _not_ one, due to the explicit `W` suffix!

Comment: [MAKEINTATOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-makeintatom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st parameter of `CreateWindowW()` takes an `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`) pointer, but `RegisterClassExW()` returns an `ATOM` (`unsigned short`) handle instead.

> lpClassName
>
> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> A null-terminated string **or a class atom created by a previous call to the RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx function. The atom must be in the low-order word of lpClassName; the high-order word must be zero.** If lpClassName is a string, it specifies the window class name. The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx, provided that the module that registers the class is also the module that creates the window. The class name can also be any of the predefined system class names. For a list of system class names, see the Remarks section.

So you would need a type-cast. Use the [`MAKEINTATOM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-makeintatom) macro for that:

> Converts the specified atom into a string, so it can be passed to functions which accept either atoms or strings.

```cpp
ATOM clsAtom = RegisterClassExW(&wcon);
if (!clsAtom) {
    // error handling ...
}
...
HWND hConnect = CreateWindowW(
        MAKEINTATOM(clsAtom), // lpClassName,
        ...
    );
```

`WC_COMBOBOX` compiles because it is defined as a string literal `L"ComboBox"` or `"ComboBox"`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

That said, your `MyRegisterConnectClass()` is declared as returning an `ATOM`, but is not actually `return`'ing anything, so the value of that returned `ATOM` is *indeterminate*.  You need to change this:

```cpp
ATOM MyRegisterConnectClass(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    ...
    RegisterClassExW(&wcon);
}
```

To this:

```cpp
ATOM MyRegisterConnectClass(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    ...
    return RegisterClassExW(&wcon); // <-- add 'return'!
}
```

And change this:

```cpp
BOOL InitConnect(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hConnect = CreateWindowW(
        RegisterClassExW(&wcon), // lpClassName,
        ...
}
```

To this:

```cpp
BOOL InitConnect(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    ATOM clsAtom = MyRegisterConnectClass(hInstance);
    if (!clsAtom) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    HWND hConnect = CreateWindowW(
        MAKEINTATOM(clsAtom), // lpClassName,
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The missing return was a typo on my part.  The MAKEINTATOM macro was some secret sauce. Brilliant.